# Django - Register custom values for sharing url

Tags: python, django

I want to add a share function. I want to register in a model what suffix it should have and later the builder should build a url from this (and of course redirect the user).

Example: 
`example.com/article/the-best-article` should be converted into this: `example.com/sU74?a` (That's just an random id)

Another example:
`example.com/poll/what-is-your-thought` should be converted into this:
`example.com/sU74?p` (The ids are the same but they are different models!)

I want to register the suffix this way:

```
class Poll(RandomIdMixin):
    # RandomIdMixin is a abstract model which creates random ids for the model
    # some fields
    @share.register
    def suffix(self):
        return "p"

    def share_builder(self):
        # return shared builder
        # this should return the short url
```

I don't know if this is possible or not. Thanks for your help

Comment: Where is the rest of the ID coming from?

Comment: From the abstract model `RandomIdMixin`. It creates via `pre_save` random ids.

Comment: I edited the post. Idk what to do. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why can't you just return id + suffix?

Comment: Yes I want to do that but I also want to "register" it. In should know that (for example) "a", as a suffix, refers to an article. P stands for poll etc.. So when somebody uses an short url it should remember that.